# Access Environment Variables in production.rb in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq, capistrano3

I want to access the environment variables in production.rb , so I have created a .bashfile & write the variable like export key = value.
I am able to get those variables in rails console but sidekiq is not taking them for sending mails , I am using capistrano for deployment.

Comment: Rails console you run yourself, in an interactive shell? And sidekiq is launched at startup by a supervisor/init process? Most likely, it doesn't load that bashfile, because its session is not interactive. If you start sidekiq yourself, does it work then?

Comment: Use the files under config/initailizers as per your requirement or contants.rb can be referred to place and fetch the values